# richfaces fileupload tab stop

Tags: jquery, richfaces

we need to make our application keyboard accessible. but for the RF fileupload component, I am unable to set focus on "upload" button. (it only displays after the add button hided) I am thinking about using JQuery, but I can't capture the event after "add" and before "upload". the onadd event seems to be removed somehow.
we are using RF 4.3, jsf 2.1. anyone has any ideas?